# Coordinate data with spaces instead of points imported as character class: how can this be cleaned?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Sorry in advance for the complicated post; this is a (very frustrating) problem I've been having for quite some time.

I have a dataset that I'm in the final steps of cleaning. The last hurdle I'm attempting to overcome has to do with the way that coordinate information was input - longitude and latitude are formatted as a mix of pseudo-DMS and decimal forms, as well as some general messiness. Here's a sample of the longitude column:

`"096 34 01.63" "096 35 46.93" "96.48.838" "19* 9 41.715" "19 9 15.922"`

As you can see, the seconds far exceed 60, there is a stray decimal in `"19* 9 41.715" "19 9 15.922"`, incorrect degree values (19 9 instead of -96), signage problems, etc.

The class of these two columns are character. I've attempted to change the classes to numeric, as there is some arithmetic I must do to the seconds in order to fix them (see above) but this introduces NAs; I assume this to be a result of spaces in the entries. For reference, this is how the sample **should** look after this initial step:

`"096:34:01.63" "096:35:46.93" "96:48:838" "199:41:715" "199:15:922"`

And this is how it'll look once I clean it fully:

`"96:34:1.63" "96:35:46.93" "96:48:13.97" "96:41:11.91" "96:15:15.36"`

Is there any way to accomplish this initial step of converting the column in numeric class without introducing NAs?

Edit: Thanks for pointing out the negatives in my desired output being inconsistent.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about the clean up rules you want to apply.  For example, why to both 96 deg and 199 deg map to -96 deg?  Why is there a second double quote in front of your final "clean" entry?  Why is `838`  mapped to `13.97` seconds rather than, say, 0.838 * 60 = `50.28` seconds?  The `sf` package may ultimately be useful, but I don't know if it has any data cleaning functions.

Comment: I don't know of any package that has cleaning functions resilient enough to deal with this, to be frank.

Answer (score 0):

Up front, I'm assuming that some of the differences in your desired output are typos: negatives (unsure) and 19-to-199-to-96. I *think* the below results are consistent.

1. Remove the `*` noise.
2. Fix your stated "known problem", converting `"19 9"` to `"96"`.
3. Normalize too-many-dots, only allow one per string. e.g., `"96.48.838"` -> `"96 48.838"`

   ```r
   gsub("\\.(?=[^.]*[.])", " ", "11.22.33.44.55", perl=TRUE)
   # [1] "11 22 33 44.55"
   ```
4. Convert DM to DMS; e.g., `"96 48.838"` -> `"96 48 50.28"`, since `0.838` minutes is `50.28` seconds.
5. (Assumed) Add `0`-padding to deg/min, limit sec to 3 decimals.

```r
vec <- c("096 34 01.63", "096 35 46.93", "96.48.838", "19* 9 41.715", "19 9 15.922")
gsub("*", "", vec, fixed=TRUE) |>                               # 1
  sub("^19 ", "96 ", x = _) |> |>                               # 2
  gsub("\\.(?=[^.]*[.])", " ", x = _, perl=TRUE) |>             # 3
  strsplit(" ") |> 
  sapply(function(X) {
    X <- as.numeric(X)
    if (length(X) == 2) X <- c(floor(X[1:2]), X[2] %% 1 * 60)   # 4
    paste(c(sprintf("%02.0f", X[1:2]),                          # 5
            sprintf("%02.3f", X[3])),                           # 5
          collapse = ":")
  })
# [1] "96:34:1.630"  "96:35:46.930" "96:48:50.280" "96:09:41.715" "96:09:15.922"
```

Comment: The negatives were a typo - I was still thinking in terms of coordinates in decimal form. 
With regards to your second point, we do know for a fact that the fourth and fifth values, i.e. "19 9 41.715" and "19 9 15.922" are typos resulting from the original spreadsheet, and that they should actually be 96 degrees instead of 19. The data is, frankly, beyond messy, and I'm beginning to believe beyond repair in terms of this specific issue.

Comment: Okay, see my edit @NathanialO'Dell, it's just another `sub`

Comment: Having said that, replacing `"19"` with `"96"` does not allow the resulting numbers to match your expected output. Are you meaning `"19 9"` to `"96"` instead? I cannot reconcile `41.715` transforming to `41:11.91` in any way. @NathanialO'Dell

Comment: Full disclosure - I'm a university student doing an exploratory research project, and so methods being used here might be "off" or just generally incorrect. We have address data that allows us to check that coordinates are correct, and when for `"19 9 41.715"` we consider `"19 9"` (which we change to `"96"`) to be degrees, `"41"` to be minutes, and `"715/60"` to be the seconds, we get a coordinate that brings us to the address given. That's where `"96:41:11.91"` comes from.   
This is where my frustration is coming from, honestly - the explanation is flimsy **at best** but it works.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of `715`, In my experience with DMS vs DM, the safer assumption has always been that `## ##.###` was DM with decimal minutes instead of `DMS` with an extra dot and wrong-scaled seconds; the former is simpler, and in my experience with data I've had to deal with (whether it be scraped or human-entered), most likely the culprit. You know your data better than I, but ... that seems unlikely. Either way, the method of how to parse/normalize should help you, whichever corrective actions you take within each step.